# Hermitian operators and commutators

Tags: physics, complex-numbers

If I have three operators such that $[A,B] = C$, and I know that $A$ and $C$ are Hermitian, does it follow that $B$ is anti-hermitian?  If $A$ and $B$ were Hermitian, $C$ would be anti-Hermitian, so $B$ clearly isn't Hermitian (unless its trivial); but I'm having trouble coming up with a counter example or a proof.  (The specific problem I'm interested in has $C$ equal to a nonzero constant, if that helps.)

Comment: It is not true that _for every_ $B$ with $[A,B]=C$, $B$ is anti-hermitian. If it were, you can always add $A$ to $B$ without changing the commutator making the resulting $B$ clearly not anti-hermitian. I suspect that you can always find _a_ $B$ such that $B$ is antihermitian and the commutator relation is fulfilled.